# I don't understand 'self' in Python class

Tags: python, class, self

So, what I know about python class is that if I want to assign values to instance attributes, I have to use self, something like this:

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
    def calculation(self):
        return self.num1*self.num2
```

This is understandable, since I know that java also uses similiar things like 'this' to specfically refer to instance attributes, but what I don't understand here is that even in other functions in the class I have to use self(like calculation() in the code), even if the function doesn't have parameters that have the same name. I feel like there's got to be better way to write instance attributes than this.

Is it true that I have to use self every time I write instance attributes? If not, what are some other ways to write instance attributes?

Comment: Note there are also "class methods" in addition to "instance methods". Note though that `calculation()` is not a candidate though as it requires `self.num1` to produce a result. If you did not pass `self` to `calculation()`, what would the meaning of `self.num1` resolve to?

Comment: When I didn't pass self to calculation() and excluded self in self.num1 and self.num2, it just didn't work.

Comment: once you create an instance of your class `x = Myclass(10, 20)` you can `print(x.calculation())` and since `x` is and instance and `calculation()` an instance method, it will be passed `x` as `self`. Essentially the same as doing `print(Myclass.calculation(x))`